# vim: no mapping found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

Every time vim starts it shows 'No mapping found' warnings.

I'm using the tutorial below to set up vim for rails development.
http://biodegradablegeek.com/2007/12/using-vim-as-a-complete-ruby-on-rails-ide/

I noticed that removing the lines below in .vimrc solves the issue

```
map :cp
map :cn
```

Question: what do those lines do and what does the warning actually mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have the html broken there, if you look at the source code what they want to do is map the alt-n and alt-p keywords, so you should add this to your .vimrc

```
map <silent> <M-p> :cp<CR>
map <silent> <M-n> :cn<CR>
```